# ASAv VM version

Tags: cisco-asa

Where can I find the VM version for the ASAv or how? I have tried to search it using cli and i couldn't find it as well as I searched on ASDM I was able to find only the resource not the version.

Thank you,
Rasha

Comment: `show version`?